# Can someone explain to me the output of this code?

Tags: java

I am confused on the output of the code. I want to know for each call on variables i and s, which class is used to call the variables. The question involves variable shadowing. Also I want to know how s keeps on changing throughout the lines in the main method.

```
public class A {
    public int i = 0;
    public static String s = "";

    public A(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
        s += "x";
    }

    public A debug() {
        if (this instanceof B) {
            System.out.println("Spam");
            s += "s";
        }
        return this;
    }
}
public class B extends A {
    public int i = 100;
    public static String s = "s";

    public B(int i, String s) {
        super(i);
        this.i += 5;
        this.s = s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        String s = "";
        B b = new B(0, s);
        System.out.println(b.i + " " + b.s);
        s += "foo";
        A a = new B(42, s);
        System.out.println(a.i + " " + a.s);
        System.out.println(b.debug().s + " " + b.i + " " + b.s);
        System.out.println(a.debug().s + " " + a.i + " " + a.s);
    }
}
```

Here is the output of that code:

```
0
105
42
0 xx
Spam
xxs 105 foo
Spam
xxss 0 xxss
```

Comment: Insert the code here...what if it will be removed from that website? The question will be useless then.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You asked "how to get the output in question number 3." The code that produces that output appears right above it, right? So to get that output, run that code. What am i misunderstanding?

Comment: The question is a bit awkwardly worded, but apparently they're asking "why does the code produce that output".

Comment: @user2966968 Which specific part of the output don't you understand?  It seems straightforward to me.  Which line don't you follow?

Comment: I don't understand the outputs starting from System.out.println(b.i + " " + b.s); in the main method.

Comment: This happens because the references to fields are resolved based on the type of the expression before the dot, not based on the class of the object that it references.  In this case, the expression `b.debug()` has type `A`.  This means that `b.debug().s` is the `s` defined in class `A`, not the `s` defined in class `B`, even though `b.debug()` is an object of class `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class A {
    public int i = 0; //not changed, because it is not overrided
    public static String s = "";

    public A(int i) {
        System.out.println(i); //1. 0, 3. 42
        s += "x"; //After second run s="xx", because it is static
    }

    public A debug() {
        if (this instanceof B) {
            System.out.println("Spam"); //5, 7. Spam
            s += "s"; //s = "xxs", than "xxss" because it is static
        }
        return this;
    }
}
public class B extends A {
    public int i = 100;
    public static String s = "s";

    public B(int i, String s) {
        super(i);
        this.i += 5; //First run: i=105, Second run: i=47
        this.s = s; //First run: public static String s="", Second run: public static String a.s="foo"
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        String s = "";
        B b = new B(0, s);
        System.out.println(b.i + " " + b.s); //2. 105
        s += "foo"; //B.s is now foo
        A a = new B(42, s); 
        System.out.println(a.i + " " + a.s); //3. 0 xx
        System.out.println(b.debug().s + " " + b.i + " " + b.s); //1. because of (A)b.s = xxs, 2. b.i = 105, 3. b.s = foo
        System.out.println(a.debug().s + " " + a.i + " " + a.s); //(A)a.s = "xxss",  (A)a.i = 0, (A)a.s = "xxss"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it understandable?

Comment: can you tell me where I can learn about the topics involving this question? I can't seem to find sources that explains the topics of shadowing and overriding properly.

Comment: You can try to debug the code too...download eclipse/netbiens, create new project, add source code and debug it step by step...it is easier to understand it, when you debug it...

Comment: If I've answered your question, you can mark it like answered :)